# how to deploy factory smart contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan, contract-verification

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Car {
    
    string public model;
    address public carAddr;

    constructor( string memory _model)  {
        model = _model;
        carAddr = address(this);
    }
}

contract CarFactory {
    Car[] public cars;

    function create( string memory _model) public {
        Car car = new Car( _model);
        cars.push(car);
    }


    function create2( string memory _model, bytes32 _salt) public {
        Car car = (new Car){salt: _salt}( _model);
        cars.push(car);
    }

    
}
```

this is my smart contract in which CarFactory contract deploys the car contract so how i verify the source code for the car contract and which code I need to use

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy it? 
Are you using remix or a framework in VSCode?

If you're using Foundry, they have a good explanation in their docs.
https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/deploying

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy your `Car` smart contract using your `Car Factory` contract, you would need to have already deployed your `Car Factory`. You can do this in multiple different ways, one solution would be using **Foundry** like @ChefAharoni suggested. To do so you will need a private key and an RPC URL. You can get one for free from providers such as [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) and [Infura](https://www.infura.io/).

After getting both of these things, deploying your contract is as simple as running a command:

`$ forge create --rpc-url <your_rpc_url> --private-key <your_private_key> src/MyContract.sol:MyContract`

[Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) allows you to write your smart contract, test, and deploy script in Solidity, however, if you have any experience in Javascript there is a development framework for deploying smart contracts in Javascript/Typescript called [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/), or if you prefer Python there is one for you as well called [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Once your `Car Factory` contract is deployed, you can deploy new `Car` contracts by simply calling your `create()` and `create2()` functions.